# GUID as std::map key

Tags: c++, boost, guid, stdmap

a dictionary was defined as the following :

```
typedef boost::tuple<conn_ptr, handler_ptr, rdp_ptr> conn_tuple;
typedef std::map<GUID, conn_tuple> conn_map;
```

we got a compilation error:

> Error 9   error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'const GUID' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xstddef

Then we solve it as:

```
struct GUIDComparer
{
    bool operator()(const GUID & Left, const GUID & Right) const
    {
        // comparison logic goes here
        if( (Left.Data1 == Right.Data1) && (Left.Data2 == Right.Data2) && 
            (Left.Data3 == Right.Data3) && (memcmp(Left.Data4 , Right.Data4,sizeof(Right.Data4))==0)  )
        {   
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
typedef boost::tuple<conn_ptr, handler_ptr, rdp_ptr> conn_tuple;
typedef std::map<GUID, conn_tuple, GUIDComparer> conn_map;
```

Now, all compiled, but then we get an exception (invalid operator< )in run time.

I have no idea what is wrong, will be glad if someone could help

Comment: Also, note that `<` is "less than", not "equal to". So return `true` when `memcmp()` returns value less than zero. You implemented wrong predicate, this is why you get the exception.

Comment: @feras please see the revised answer. The previous one had an important logic error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your GUIDComparer is comparing for equality. The functor you pass to a map must generate weak ordering - i.e. it must compare less or compare greater, not equal.

this will work:

```
struct GUIDComparer
{
    bool operator()(const GUID & Left, const GUID & Right) const
    {
        // comparison logic goes here
        return memcmp(&Left , &Right,sizeof(Right)) < 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: @RichardHodges: This is much better. It's still possible that this is broken if `GUID` has padding bytes in it. But I imagine that most implementations of a GUID wouldn't have padding bytes.

Comment: agreed. I figured I'd at least get the solution logically correct (assuming that GUID is an unpadded trivial POD struct).
The full safe solution would be to write `operator<` in terms of a `compare()` function that returned -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: Dunno, was it really necessary to provide the code when that was already answered? That teaches the entirely wrong thing. Like, one does not even have to try, just go to SO to get others to write your code for you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf it's not just about the OP though. We're not a "let's help this user" service (that would be like ye olde forums/IRC). Consider e.g. the mention of POD and padding that didn't crop up under your answer.

Comment: The absense of `static_assert(std::is_pod<GUID>::value, "not applicable");` and not even a mention of POD in the answer makes me -1 this

Comment: We don't have the definition of GUID so arguing about the best way to write a comparison function for it is pointless.

Comment: I don't have the windows API in front of me at the moment. If you wish to replace the code with a safer alternative by all means go ahead.

Comment: @RichardHodges: don't be so adversarial. you don't have the windows api in front of you but you surely have this page in front of you and i provided 3 links. also the code is technically ok. which is what i wrote. ;-)

Comment: I am by no means adversarial about this. I accept the criticism of the assumption that GUID has no padding bytes. But I am on an iPad, and writing code with my thumbs is not something I relish at midnight :)

Answer (score 6):

The shown comparison operator can return `false` for both `a<b` and `b<a` when `a` does not compare as equal to `b`.

Just apply `memcmp` to the whole thing and check the result.

---

Addendum (due to sehe's comments). The `GUID` type, which this question is tagged with, is a Windows API name for a standard 128-bit UUID, *universal unique identifier*. It's guaranteed POD, and moreover guaranteed contiguous, since it's guaranteed 128 bits with every one meaningful. This makes it safe to use `memcmp`.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using Boost.UUID instead of GUID which is provided by Windows SDK.

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>

typedef std::map<boost::uuids::uuid, conn_tuple> conn_map;
```

`boost::uuids::uuid` already provides the necessary comparison operators so you don't have to write an ordering predicate as suggested in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct GUIDComparer
{
    bool operator()(const GUID & Left, const GUID & Right) const
    {enter code here
        // comparison logic goes here
        return memcmp(&Left , &Right,sizeof(Right)) < 0;
    }
};

sometimes this does not work.

it should be: return memcmp(&Left , &Right,sizeof(Right)) == -1; (not 0)
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation of what you did, or how you fixed the function?